# Overlapping Frames with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, sudoku, pysimplegui

I want to create a GUI using pySimpleGUI that resembles the Killer Sudoku game. For those unfamiliar with Killer Sudoku, it is similar to regular sudoku however there is an extra level of complexity where not only do you have the 9 3x3 boxes where the number 1-9 has to be used exactly one time per frame, column and row but there are also cages. These cages have a number that specifies what all the numbers in the cage must sum up to. No number can be repeated in the cage either. Here is an example of what one of these boards looks like.

[Killer Sudoku Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUxpL.png)

As you can see, not only would I need a frame to outline each 3x3, but also a frame for each cage on the board. The issue comes when a cage is in both a column and a row (an L shape). Does pySimpleGUI have the ability to frame abnormal shapes like what would be required for this sudoku game?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: IMO, this only way is to use `sg.Graph` and draw everything by yourself.

Comment: Would you happen to know of an example of where this is used. Or know if it would be realistic to be able to do this automatically?

Comment: Jason has the right approach. There's also a demo program in the PySimpleGUI repo that draws a crossword puzzle using a Graph Element that you may find helpful to examine.

Answer (score 1):

Show how to draw the board on `sg.Graph` in following example script, of course, not everything drawn here

There're still lot of works to do to implement your Killer Sudoku game.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Sudoku():

    def __init__(self):
        # Use monospaced font here
        self.columns = 9
        self.blocks = 3
        self.bg = 'green'
        self.line_width = (1, 3, 6)
        self.line_color = ("black", "black", 'grey')
        self.number_color = ("white", "yellow")
        self.font0 = ("Courier New", 20, 'bold')
        self.font1 = ("Courier New", 12)
        self.w0, self.h0 = self.char_size(self.font0)
        self.w1, self.h1 = self.char_size(self.font1)
        self.pad = 8
        w = self.w0 + 2 * (self.w1 + 2 * self.pad)
        h = self.h0 + 2 * self.pad
        self.cell_width = max(w, h)
        self.width = (self.cell_width * self.columns + 2 * self.line_width[2])
        self.size = (self.width, self.width)
        self.numbers0, self.numbers1 = [], []

    def char_size(self, font):
        root = sg.tk.Tk()
        size = (sg.tk.font.Font(font=font).measure("W"),
            sg.tk.font.Font(font=font).metrics('linespace'))
        root.destroy()
        return size

    def draw_board1(self, element):
        delta = self.columns * self.cell_width
        for i in range(self.columns+1):
            x = self.line_width[2] + i * self.cell_width
            x0, x1 = self.line_width[2], self.line_width[2] + delta
            y = self.line_width[2] + i * self.cell_width
            y0, y1 = self.line_width[2], self.line_width[2] + delta
            element.draw_line((x0, y), (x1, y), color=self.line_color[0],
                width=self.line_width[0])
            element.draw_line((x, y0), (x, y1), color=self.line_color[0],
                width=self.line_width[0])

    def draw_board2(self, element):
        delta = self.columns * self.cell_width
        for i in range(self.blocks+1):
            x = self.line_width[2] + 3 * i * self.cell_width
            x0, x1 = self.line_width[2], self.line_width[2] + delta
            y = self.line_width[2] + 3 * i * self.cell_width
            y0, y1 = self.line_width[2], self.line_width[2] + delta
            element.draw_line((x0, y), (x1, y), color=self.line_color[1],
                width=self.line_width[1])
            element.draw_line((x, y0), (x, y1), color=self.line_color[1],
                width=self.line_width[1])

    def draw_number0(self, element, data):
        if self.numbers0:
            element.Widget.delete(*self.numbers)
        self.numbers0 = []
        offset_x = self.line_width[2] + self.cell_width//2
        offset_y = self.cell_width*self.columns + self.line_width[2] - self.cell_width//2
        for row in range(self.columns):
            for col in range(self.columns):
                item = element.draw_text(str(data[row][col]),
                    (offset_x + self.cell_width * col, offset_y - self.cell_width * row),
                    font=self.font0, color=self.number_color[0])
                self.numbers0.append(item)

    def draw_number1(self, element, data):
        if self.numbers1:
            element.Widget.delete(*self.numbers)
        self.numbers1 = []
        offset_x = self.line_width[2] + self.pad + self.w1
        offset_y = self.cell_width*self.columns + self.line_width[2] - self.pad - self.h1//2
        for row, col, number in data:
            item = element.draw_text(str(number),
                (offset_x + self.cell_width * col, offset_y - self.cell_width * row), font=self.font1,
                color=self.number_color[1])
            self.numbers1.append(item)

s = Sudoku()
data0 = list(map(list, [
    "739541286", "168923457", "245687139", "973862541", "512374968",
    "684195372", "421738695", "397256814", "856419723"]))
data1 = [
    (0, 0, 11), (0, 2, 17), (0, 3, 9), (0, 5, 3), (0, 7, 19),
    (1, 1, 15), (1, 3, 11), (1, 5, 10), (1,6, 10), (1,8, 16),
    (2, 0, 16), (2, 3, 14), (2, 4, 16), (2, 7, 8),
    (3, 1, 8), (3, 2, 5),
    (4, 3, 14), (4, 6, 12), (4, 7, 13), (4, 8, 15),
    (5, 0, 16), (5, 2, 12), (5, 3, 13), (5, 5, 13),
    (6, 0, 7), (6, 3, 9), (6, 6, 16),
    (7, 1, 22), (7, 4, 11), (7, 6, 15), (7, 8, 9),
    (8, 2, 10), (8, 4, 10),
]

layout = [
    [sg.Graph(s.size, (0, 0), s.size, background_color=s.bg, key='GRAPH',
        enable_events=True)],
]

window = sg.Window("Killer Sudoku", layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
graph = window['GRAPH']
s.draw_board1(graph)
s.draw_board2(graph)
s.draw_number0(graph, data0)
s.draw_number1(graph, data1)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    print(event, values)
window.close()
```

[image]